# How to get dynamic numbers using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, junit

How do I get dynamically changing numbers in the span block ?

```
<div class="main-page-exchange__indicator">
   <span class="main-page-exchange__rate">72,54</span></div>
</div>
```

Method:

```
@Test
public void first(){
    chromeDriver.get("https://www.open.ru/");
    WebElement buyRateUSD = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='main-page-exchange__rate']"));
    System.out.println("out" + buyRateUSD);
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this. My method xpatch which returns the value:

```
"out[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (7ec6711c86cc8089e3bd06c161cdebf8)] -> xpath: //span[@class='main-page-exchange__rate']]"
```

How can I get dynamically changing numbers in such blocks for further comparison?

Comment: it returns value ? if so , then wahts the actual issue ?

Comment: it does not return values in the form: "72,54"

Comment: what does it return , please edit and add more details

Comment: it is written above that my method returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chromeDriver.get("https://www.open.ru/");
WebElement buyRateUSD = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='main-page-exchange__rate']"));
System.out.println("out" + buyRateUSD.getText());
```

byRaetUSD is a webelement you should call getText to get the text or you can call

```
  buyRateUSD.getAttribute("textContent")
```

if element is not in the view port as getText finds inner test and will give consideration to isdisplayed . if isdisplayed is falls getText will return empty string. getAttribute("textContent") doesn't care about isDisplayed so it will return  text if element is present

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns values of the Type [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

To get the text in that you need to use `buyRateUSD.getText()` this should give you the text as a String and you can parse it further to use it.

Comment: If you write: buyRateUSD.getText();
System.out. println ("exit" + purchase rate in US dollars);
then it will still return the type WebElement. the PDHide option is working, but I do not know why and how to use the get.Text() method without referring to System.out. println().

Comment: See the linked doc, it will return a `String`. And I am not sure I understand your comment about how ot use getText() without System.out...